# Leaflet point search from JSON?

Tags: leaflet, json

i tried create simple code for searching in JSON point feature layer (us_states) but i dont know, why it is not working. What can be wrong with this code?

```
        // Map data and base layer
        var data = us_states;
        var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 5, center: new L.latLng([37.8, -96]) });

        map.addLayer(new 
        L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));  //base layer
        var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();            
        var featuresLayer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
                onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
                    marker.bindPopup('<h4 style="color:'+feature.properties.color+'">'+ feature.properties.OBJECTID +'</h4>');
                }
            });

        map.addLayer(featuresLayer);                
        map.addLayer(markersLayer);    
        var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
            position:'topright',        
            layer: markersLayer,
            initial: false,
            zoom: 12,
            marker: false
        });

        map.addControl( controlSearch );
        for(d in featuresLayer) {
            var title = featuresLayer[d].OBJECTID,  //value searched
                loc = featuresLayer[d].loc,     //position found
                marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {OBJECTID: OOBJECTID} );//se property searched
            marker.bindPopup('OBJECTID: '+ OBJECTID );
            markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? You can see the map and the features but cannot search?

Comment: yes,  i can search, but when i click on search panel with name it does nothing, note move map to point nothing

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your data? The data is in polygons or points? Also you would probably wanna change `{OBJECTID: OOBJECTID}` to `{OBJECTID: OBJECTID}`

Comment: thanks, data are points,  this is maybe problem ...  i see oobjectid, but i think that i have tried this with correct name and still not working

Comment: Sure thing. If you will a Jsfiddle I'll check it out. What happens if you console log in the featuresLayer loop? Does the markersLayer is populated with the right data?

Comment: Thanks for your excellent fast comment. It is not working, location not found,  i want  modifi this http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/simple.html  there is in input points manuly in code,  i want link points from my JSON file with same function, searching a zoom to seacrh point. Search atribute in mine is OBJECTID. This is structure my JSON http://jpeg.cz/images/2017/07/24/P1KwG.png

Comment: I can't see a 'loc' property in your json, only lat/lng.

Comment: of course,  i have tried with atribute loc,  the same result, not working search

Comment: I want only modifi this simple example with input data,  with my  external loadin from JSON, but it is not working, I am exhausted and angry with leaflet

Comment: I can see that in order to use this plugin you need node.js and installing the search-leaflet npm. There are other options such as [link](https://github.com/utahemre/Leaflet.GeoJSONAutocomplete). Good luck! Leaflet is really great in my opinion, don't give up on it so soon.